# upload multiple files - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, has-many

I already have a project in which I can upload multiple images, but I am missing the most important thing, being able to relate them to a post id number or record from another table. I am doing the upload with a DropZone.

Model File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['url','siniestro_id'];

    
    public function siniestro()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo('App\models\Siniestro');
    }


}
```

Model Siniestro

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Wildside\Userstamps\Userstamps;



class Siniestro extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Userstamps;
   
    protected $fillable = ['created_by', 'imagen', 'updated_by', 'deleted_by', 'siniestro', 'patente', 'cliente', 'fechaip', 'estado', 'modalidad',
    'observaciones', 'fechacierre', 'compania', 'contacto', 'codigoinspeccion', 'inspector', 'direccion', 'localidad', 'telefono', 'motivo', 'link', 'enviarorden', 'email'];


   

   public function files()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\models\File');
   }


}
```

File controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\File;
use App\Models\Siniestro;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class fileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('files.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('files.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $imagenes = $request->file('file')->store('public/imagenes');

        $url = Storage::url($imagenes);

        //return $url; // <- verifica lo que devuelve el submit del formulario

        File::create([
            'url' => $url,
            'siniestro_id' => $siniestro->id,
            
        ]);
          

        
    }
```

[view of the relationship that I made in my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZIhG.png)

View edit where I want to upload the images

```
@can('editar-siniestro')
                                <form action="{{ route('siniestros.update',$siniestro->id) }}" method="POST">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('PUT')
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="siniestro">Siniestros</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="siniestro" class="form-control" disabled value="{{ $siniestro->siniestro }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="patente">Patente</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="patente" class="form-control" disabled value="{{ $siniestro->patente }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="link">Link 2.0</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control" disabled value="{{ $siniestro->link }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                            
                                    <label for="lugar">Lugar de inspección</label>
                                    <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" for="lugar" name="lugar" value="{{ $siniestro->lugar}}">
                                            <option selected>-- seleccionar --</option>
                                            <option value="TH">Taller homologado</option>
                                            <option value="Taller del asegurado">Taller del asegurado</option>
                                            <option value="Domicilio particular">Domicilio particular</option>
                                            
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                        
                                    
                                        
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="Estado">Estado</label>
                                        <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" for="estado" name="estado" value="{{ $siniestro->estado }}">
                                                <option selected>{{ $siniestro->estado }}</option>
                                                <option value="Coordinado">Coordinado</option>
                                                <option value="Ausente">Ausente</option>
                                                <option value="Derivado">Derivado</option>
                                                <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <label for="modalidad">Tipo de inspeccion</label>   
                                        <select class="form-select col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" aria-label="Default select example" for="modalidad" name="modalidad" value="{{ $siniestro->modalidad }}"> 
                                                <option selected>{{ $siniestro->modalidad }}</option>
                                                <option value="Presencial">Presencial</option>
                                                <option value="Videollamada">Videollamada</option>
                                                <option value="Por foto">Por foto</option>
                                                <option value="Por foto y presupuesto">Por foto y presupuesto</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mt-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="direccion">Dirección</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="direccion" class="form-control" value="{{ $siniestro->direccion }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="fechaip">Fecha IP</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="fechaip" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mt-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="localidad">Localidad</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="localidad" class="form-control" value="{{ $siniestro->localidad }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mt-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="enviarorden">Enviar orden</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="enviarorden" class="form-control" value="{{ $siniestro->enviarorden }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 mt-2">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="motivo">Motivo</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" value="{{ $siniestro->motivo }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $siniestro->email }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">                 
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="observaciones">Observaciones</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="observaciones" style="height: 100px" value="{{ $siniestro->observaciones }}">{{ $siniestro->observaciones }}</textarea>                                
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirmar Cambios</button>
                                     
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form action="{{route('files.store')}}" method="POST"
                            
                            class="dropzone"
                            id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                            
                            </form>
                                @endcan
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I'm really not sure if I should do it from the controller "file", or if I should do it directly from the "siniestro" controller... to be clear, I need the files to take the "siniestro_id" from siniestros id primary key to which they belong, that is, in which they are uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store file and siniestros at the same time or store file first?

Anyway, we recommend you to create `FileService` and `SiniestroService` to handle the logic.

`FileController`/`SiniestroController` can call `FileService`/`SiniestroService` (pass params as well)

`FileService` can call `SiniestroService`, and vice verse (pass params as well)

**Workflow**: `route` **<->** `controller` **<->** `service` **<->** `repository`

A simple example is [here](https://bestofphp.com/repo/yaza-putu-laravel-repository-with-service-php-miscellaneous)

*(Note: You can read about validation, middleware, ...)*